# C++11 GCC 4.6.2 std::move

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I tried to use move constructor, with std::move

```
#include <utility>
```

But I receive an error, ‘move’ is not a member of ‘std’.

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1)
```

I understand move constructor is a new feature in C++11, just wondering whether it is available in gcc 4.6.2 yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the flag `-std=c++0x`(changed to -std=c++1x for gcc 4.7)

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: It's changed to `c++11` in 4.7...

Comment: It's not changed! "GCC 4.7 and later support `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11` as well" ([source](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)), i.e. additionally to, not instead of `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you compile with the C++0x flag on (`-std=c++0x`)? g++ defaults to C++03.

Comment: Precision: without this flag some portions of the headers are stripped out (using typical `#ifdef` code), and among them the definition of `std::move`.