# What include am I missing?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the following program:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[]) {
  std::function<int(int, int)> f = [i, &j] { return i + j; };
  std::cout << f(5, 5);
}
```

Why do I get the following error:

```
a.cc:17:3: error: \u2018function\u2019 is not a member of \u2018std\u2019
```

Even if I replace it with "auto" the compiler complains that "f" doesn't name a type. I tried with GCC 4.4.3 and 4.6.2.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408082/c11-gcc-4-6-2-stdmove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::function<int(int, int)> f = [i, &j] { return i + j; };
```

That is wrong syntax.

What you actually want to write is this:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> f =[](int i, int j) { return i + j; };
```

Or if you want to use `auto`, then:

```
auto f =[](int i, int j) { return i + j; };
```

Use `-std=c++0x` option with gcc-4.6.2 to compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

[Polymorphic wrappers for function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Polymorphic_wrappers_for_function_objects)  are new in C++11. To use these features in a pre-4.7 GCC installation that supports C++0x (the draft version of C++11), you need to compile with the `-std=c++0x` switch (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)).

For GCC v4.7, that is switched to `-std=c++11` (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)).